# morphia query by comparing fields

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

```
public class MyObject{
    private String string1;
    private Long long1;
    private String string2;
    .......//other states
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something like

```
public List find(MyObject o){
    return morphiaDatastore.find(o);
}
```

I'm expecting all MyObjects whose string1 is "someValue" and string3 is "otherValue". How do I do this with morphia? I know we can use standard Query, but user may choose any of the existing fields as criteria and standard Query approach also doesn't do well with object structure refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a **[`Query`](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query)** object and specifying a **[`filter`](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#filter)** to get the results you want:

```
Query query = datastore.createQuery(MyObject.class)
                       .filter("string1 = ", "someValue")
                       .filter("string3 = ", "otherValue");
```

In the above, specify the class you want to query for, `MyObject`, and filters to the **`createQuery()`** method. Once you've defined the query, use the `asList()` method to access the results:

```
List<MyObject> objects = query.asList();
```

Morphia's filter operators closely map to the query operators used in MongoDB queries. The `=` operator in the above query is analogous to the **`$eq`** operator in MongoDB.

As an alternative to filter queries, Morphia offers a **[`fluent`](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#fluent-interface)** interface for building queries. The following fluent-interface query, for example, is identical to the preceding filter query:

```
Query query = datastore.createQuery(MyObject.class)
                       .field("string1").equal("someValue")
                       .field("string3").equal("otherValue");
```

Comment: yes, I know about filter and field method, but this will break everytime there's a change to POJO structure. the query is guaranteed to use only "equals" operator, so is there a way to just pass a "comparison" object when querying?

Comment: In your quuestion you asked _I'm expecting all MyObjects whose string1 is "someValue" and string3 is "otherValue". How do I do this with morphia?_ and the above addresses that, now I'm not sure what the comparison operator you are asking in the above context.

Comment: I've updated the snippet. so with this, user may construct their own object. user A may filter by field 1 and 3, and user B by field 2, 3 and 5, and so on.